# Broken parameters persisting in Deis deployments

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, deis

An invalid `command` parameter got into the deployment for a worker process in a Deis app. Now whenever I run a `deis pull` for a new image this broken parameter gets passed to the deployment so the worker doesn't start up successfully.

If I go into kubectl I can see the following parameter being set in the deployment for the worker (path `/spec/template/spec/containers/0`)

```
"command": [
  "/bin/bash",
  "-c"
],
```

Which results in the pod not starting up properly:

```
Error: failed to start container "worker": Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/bash\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory"
Error syncing pod
Back-off restarting failed container
```

This means that for every release/pull I've been going in and manually removing that parameter from the worker deployment setup. I've run `kubectl delete deployment` and recreated it with valid json (`kubectl create -f deployment.json`). This fixes things until I run `deis pull` again, at which point the broken parameter is back.

My thinking is that that broken `command` parameter is persisted somewhere in the deis database or the like and that it's being reset when I run `deis pull`.

I've tried [the troubleshooting guide](https://deis.com/docs/workflow/troubleshooting/kubectl/) and dug around in the `deis-database` but I can't find where the deployment for the worker process is being created or where the deployment parameters that get passed to kubernetes when you run a `deis pull` come from.

Running deis v2.10.0 on Google Cloud